# Process to make magento extension(plugin) live on magento market place

Tags: magento, marketplace

Any one can explain the process to make magento extension live on magento marketplace platform.

Answer (score 0):

The process of submission of an extension to Magento Marketplace consists in passing the following four reviews:

1. **Business Review** - reviewing the business problem which your extension solves. You are expected to describe properly the unique approach that extension uses to solve a meaningful business problem.
2. **Technical Review** - performed by a set of tests specific for your extension. The technical review is automated, based on the validation of the structure of the extension, compliance with the coding standard, check for viruses/malware and plagiarism check. My advices for passing in the first time: Make sure your extension is built as per the coding standards and validate it with the Code Sniffer rules and sniffs for your Magento platform. If the extension is for Magento 2, test the installation of your extension with Composer and make sure it works with all dependencies involved.
3. **QA Review** - a manual review covering the quality of the code. I pass this review without comments from a reviewer and cannot provide details on it. What I can advise you is to follow the Magento standards and the good software development practices in general and perform your own review based on the highest criteria for code quality that you can satisfy.
4. **Marketing Review** - a manual review on the short and detailed descriptions, extension icon, images, videos (if any), compatibility with Magento platforms and web browsers (web browsers compatibility is optional), pricing, installation and extension support (both are optional), documentation (at least one user guide or reference manual or installation guide) and some other minor details. A challenge in this review might be the long description of your extension and following the reviewer's requests that are given to you in a unidirectional communication, i.e. you do not have the option to ask, discuss or express your point of view.

I advise you to have the following prepared before starting the submission of your extension:

1. **Your extension**. It should be built as per the Magento ECG (Expert Consulting Group) and Magento EQP (Extension Quality Program) coding standards (or EcgM2 and MEQP2 if your module is for Magento 2).
2. **User guide for your extension in PDF format**. It does not need to be huge, so focus on the quality of the content and usability of the guide. Summarising the essentials in at least 5-6 pages would be fine, and certainly, you can make it as long as you want.
3. **Short description**. You have 250 characters to describe what your extension does in a sentence or two. You can write this on the go while doing the submission, but I advise you to have this prepared before starting.
4. **Detailed description**. You have 5000 characters to describe your extension in details by using HTML tags. Similarly to the short description, you can write this on the go while doing the submission, but I still advise you to have a well-written detailed description before starting.
5. **Extension icon**. It should be 240x240px in JPG, JPEG or PNG format.
6. **Images/screenshots**. You need to upload at least 2 and at most 15 images, up to 5MB each, in JPG, JPEG or PNG format.
7. **Videos**. Videos are optional. If you want to include videos, keep in mind that only YouTube is supported.

For the smooth experience in the submission process to Magento Marketplace, I would also advise you:

1. Follow the Magento coding standards and the good software development practices as much as you can. Not following a specific rule of the Magento coding standards for a good reason might be fine (if you look at the Magento code, you will see they do not always obey their coding standard in full either), but as a rule of thumb, I advise you to play by the rules always when it is possible and reasonable.
2. Keep in mind that your extension is expected to run on all PHP versions supported by all claimed Magento versions. For example, if you mark that your extension supports Magento 2.0.x, it should run on PHP 5 down to 5.5.22 or it will be rejected.
3. In order to accelerate the marketing review, include as a bare minimum an overview of your company (or the company of your client), the features of your extension, how Magento will function and appear with your extension and format your headings by using H3 HTML tags, which in my submissions were always required. Based on the category where you are submitting and other factors, you might be required to include additional information as well.
4. In order to accelerate the submission process as a whole, you can submit your extension for both technical and marketing review at the same time.